# XCode analyzer give wrong "potential memory leak" issue?

Tags: iphone, xcode, memory-leaks

I write a function such as follows to create a CGPath:

```
+(CGPathRef)CGPathCreateRoundrect:(CGRect)rect radius:(CGFloat)radius {
    CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
    ......
    CGPathCloseSubpath(path);
    return path;
}
```

The analyzer says the first line of code create a object that is potentially leaked. But i do want to create a new object in this function and transfer ownership to the caller. And the function name contains the key word "Create". Is this a bug of "Analyzer"?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is happening because according to compiler understanding a `+()` method will always return autoreleased variable which is not in your case.

Comment: this works as a rule for compiler even if you are releasing it in the caller method (which compiler does not know!!)

Comment: @user1095341 No, I don't believe this is correct.  Class methods (`+`) are not treated any differently than instance methods (`-`) when it comes to the naming conventions that the Clang Static Analyzer observes.  As Williham points out, the analyzer is calling you on having a method that is not prefixed with “alloc”, “new”, “copy”, or “mutableCopy”, as stated by the guidelines here: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000994-BAJHFBGH . Being a class method vs. an instance method has no bearing here.

Answer (score 3):

The analyzer is acting correctly here. Ownership is only transferred by methods named `copy`, `init`, or some variation thereof.

The object returned should be autoreleased.

Comment: Don't forget about the `new` prefix, as well.

Comment: @BradLarson: Why not? Everyone else did. ;)